# Horizontally center embedded Google Doc?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I'm new to HTML and CSS, and have been learning through HTML for dummies.

Anyway, I was wondering how I would go about horizontally centering an embedded google doc.

```css
div#iframe-wrapper iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  right: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body bgcolor="#414141">
  <title>Rules Page</title>
  <div class="center">
    <iframe width='85%' height='100%' src="https://docs.google.com/document/d/1G1xhqhSK2Ge8diyXELZ3cNvFJj-5wK-0_1VMjCfQR_I/pub?embedded=true">    </iframe>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I horizontally center an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-can-i-horizontally-center-an-element)

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the way to do it

```css
.center iframe {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#414141">
<title>Rules Page</title>
    <div class="center">
        <iframe width='85%' height='100%' src="https://docs.google.com/document/d/1G1xhqhSK2Ge8diyXELZ3cNvFJj-5wK-0_1VMjCfQR_I/pub?embedded=true">    </iframe>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that still isn't centered. For reference, here's http://evilmelonrp.com/texastestrules/ my doc in the webpage.

Comment: You need to select `body` that is inside `iframe` and then apply the CSS given above to the `body` inside `iframe`. You cannot select the `body` using CSS but you can select using JavaScript/jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to do.

IFRAME has fixed width, and you can't access the body due to CORS.